# GET request is not working in React Component

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, get, babeljs

I already imported the `axios` library and the `React`. I am making a get call in a `React` component, Request is proper and returning response also, it gives me this:

```
{"functionality": [
         {"category": "", "price": 2.0, "moltiplicator": 100.0, "name": "Plat"}
  ]
}
```

but when i am setting the response to state variable, it is not working, this is code:

```
export class FetchDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/get_platforms`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            posts: res.functionality
          });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map(post =>
            <li >{post.category}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The response from `axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/get_platforms`)`  is a JSON string or a JS object?

Comment: are you sure about console.llog(res.functionality)???

please also place res in paranthesis axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/get_platforms`).then((res) => {...}

Comment: is a json string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your handling of the response, you should use `res.data`, not only `res`:

```
export class FetchDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/get_platforms`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            posts: res.data.functionality
          });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map(post =>
            <li >{post.category}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATE: see the example from the axios: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/examples/get/index.html